# File to import not found or unreadable with Jekyll and Sass

Tags: sass, jekyll

I am trying to link to a sass library I downloaded via node.

The error I'm getting:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/styles.scss':
   Error: File to import not found or unreadable: @library/path/src/index.scss. on line 3:1
   of @library/path/src/index.scss from line 3:1 of _sass/styles.scss from line 1:1
   of styles.scss >> @import '@library/path/src/index'; ^ 
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.0.0   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace.
```

My sass file looks like:

```css
@import '@library/path/src/index';
```

I added to my package.json file:

```js
"sass": {
    "includePaths": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

The only hint the library gives of something that I'm missing is `First, make sure your build system is configured so that the node_modules directory is in the list of Sass includePaths.` I'm not sure where I can confirm that.

Note: this doesn't even work even if I link directly to the file in `node_modules`

```css
../node_modules/@library/path/src/index.scss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I had to add to my config.yml

```
  load_paths:
    - _sass
    - node_modules
```